# Knockout JS: Showing incorrect values in "select" tag

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

The view model:

```
function Specialization(id, name) {
            var self = this;
            self.id = id;
            self.name = name;
        }

        function ObservableSpecialization() {
            var self = this;
            self.availableItem = ko.observable();
        }

        function ViewModel() {
            var self = this;
            self.specializations = ko.observableArray([]);
            self.availableSpecializations = [];

            self.addSpecialization = function () {
                self.specializations.push(new Specialization());
            }
            self.removeSpecialization = function (specialization) {
                self.specializations.remove(specialization)
            }
        }
```

Document Loading:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var model = new ViewModel();

            var temp = [];
            $.each(window.availableSpecializations, function (i, item) {
                var specialization = new Specialization(item.ID, item.Name);
                model.availableSpecializations.push(specialization);
                temp.push(item.ID);
            });
            $.each(window.userSpecializations, function (i, item) {

                var idx = temp.indexOf(item.ID);
                if (idx != -1) {
                    var available = model.availableSpecializations[idx];
                    var specialization = new ObservableSpecialization();
                    specialization.availableItem = available;
                    model.specializations.push(specialization);
                }
            });

            ko.applyBindings(model);
        });
```

`<select>` snippet:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: specializations">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <select name="Specializations" data-bind="options: $root.availableSpecializations, value: 'availableItem', optionsText: 'name'">
                                </select>
                            </td>
```

Result:

As you can see below, all the values are always set to the first item in the list.. I guess the ID is not binding to selected item somehow... where am I going wrong?

[image]

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, you want it to show "please select" or something like that instead of the first item in the array?  Have you tried optionsCaption: 'Please Choose One...' after the value attribute?

Comment: No.. after selecting a couple of items.. I save it correctly, with the correct values.. but when I come back to the page to edit the values again, then they are both set to "Cardiology" instead of what they were saved as.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 problems: 
First, `specialization.availableItem` is an observable and so should be assigned with a function call: `specialization.availableItem(available)`

Second, in the binding string you have `value: 'availableItem'` which just sets the select value to the string 'availableItem'. Should be without the quotes: `value: availableItem`

Here's a fiddle with the 2 fixes: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/antishok/xrETq/37/)